# Email not sent on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, amazon

I am using Magento 2 on Host Amazon LightSail:

https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/

But email is not working (sent email when register, forget password, place order, ...)

So, I installed Extension SMTP extension and it is working fine and Email is working:

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp

(Also I tried many extensions for smtp and all working fine)

But I have a problem, that the email is sent with the header which is set  as a username config authentication in extension backend. It is supposed to be the real email set in magento backend for `General Contact, Sales Email, Customer Support, ...`

Is there any answer to make email working without any extension? **OR**
If I continue with the extension, how can I make the email sent with the correct header which set?

Comment: Hi, Were you able to solve it? We are facing a similar problem.

Comment: Hi, I replied below.

Answer (score 2):

I tried MailGun Provider with the extension mentioned in the question and it is working fine.

Comment: extension url send